# Short movies on YouTube resembling Half Life

Tags: story-identification, short-film, half-life

I am trying to identify two short movies I watched on YouTube years ago.

- They were live action movies,
- Both took place in same universum, that was clearly inspired by *Half Life* series, but were not using the brand,
- I think even some sound effects from the game were used,
- first movie was filmed in first person, and was mainly about fighting enemies looking almost like Combine soldiers (they even made those incopmperhesible radio chatter noises),
- there was a gun that made enemy vomit,
- there was a giant, omnious, glowing object (a tower? a spaceship?) in a center of what looked like abandoned city,
- there was a strange, glowing cube in posession of main character,
- in second movie there was a couple, and it looked all but normal, but at some point they heard a strange, omnious noise, they looked toward some city, and there was this strage object (tower/spacechip) from the first movie.

Answer (score 10):

I found this thanks to Reddit: [Does anybody remember the short film "what's in the box" that people thought was a half life 3 ARG?](https://www.reddit.com/r/HalfLife/comments/6c8m5a/does_anybody_remember_the_short_film_whats_in_the/).
Once I knew the title I also found the second short, which I remember seeing separate from the first one (it seems it's now gone from yt, but here it is as a part of an edit )

and I found that there was a third short also

Answer (score 5):

Presumably this is [*Half-Life: Escape from City 17*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-Life:_Escape_from_City_17) (2009, 2011). It’s not actually first person but is filmed in a way that looks like it is first person. *Part One* is set in between *Half-Life 2* and *Half-Life 2: Episode One*.

Comment: I am 100% sure this isn't it. Although both movies I'm looking for were clearly taking inspiration (bordering straight copying) from _Half Life_ universum, they were not using _Half Life_ in the title

Comment: @psych4tog not all of the YouTube videos of this shirt film mention Half-Life in the title. For example, the one I linked in my answer.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - Vomit gun?

Comment: @Valorum I didn’t watch the full thing. In any case it’s a close enough match without a vomit gun to be worth a try.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - Sure, but the vomit gun seems like quite a memorable feature

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot good point, Youtube videos get reposted all the time; and the repost is likely to have a different title.